# How do I embed a google form into a webpage compatible with IE, Chrome, and Firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe

How do I embed a google form into a webpage? I've tried iframe but it doesn't seem to work in IE or Chrome. I don't have access to using a database so that method wont work. I have created a form via the web and one via google forms but can't seem to figure out how to extract the data entered into a spreadsheet. I've tried searching for an answer but can't find one.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I embed a google form into a webpage? I've tried iframe but it doesn't seem to work in IE or Chrome. I

You can't. Google forbid it with the `X-Frame-Options` response header.

Just link to it instead.

> can't seem to figure out how to extract the data entered into a spreadsheet

Click the sheets icon on the form page.

[image: Google Forms screenshot]